# change xml data in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I got acces to a XML file with the following data:

```
<VertrekTijd>2014-05-26T11:15:00+0200</VertrekTijd>
```

I use the following code to read this data:

```
case "VertrekTijd": lblv1.Text = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
```

I recieve this in my label:

```
2014-05-26T11:15:00+0200
```

How do i get only the:

> 11:15

I looked around here but i didn't find any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use parsed time data from DateTime:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse( "2014-05-26T11:15:00+0200", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var res = date.Hour + ":" + date.Minute;
```

Another way is direct parsing with regular expression:

```
var res = Regex.Match("2014-05-26T11:15:00+0200", @"\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}").Value;
```

Yet another way is to play with `string.Split` and similar, but I wouldn't do that if you care about you mental health...

Comment: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems' - Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your time into a `DateTime` object and then present it:

```
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParse("2014-05-26T11:15:00+0200", out dateTime))
{
    lblv1.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute);
}
```

Comment: this will return "11:15:00", not "11:15"